# Including modules in a Perl exe generated with PAR::Packer

Tags: perl

```
> test_dir
>        |_test.pl
>        |_modules_dir
>                    |_config.pm
>          |_helper.pm
>          |_mech.pm
```

I want to make .exe file I already installed "PAR::Packer" and it working fine. I tested a temporary script(check.pl) using this command "pp -o check.exe check.pl"

I want to make .exe but also attach the modules_dir, which command I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-a` or `--addfile=FILE|DIR` options of pp utility.

example usage:

```
pp -a /path/to/your/include/dir out.exe hello
```

Please look for other pp options here [https://metacpan.org/pod/pp](http://metacpan.org/pod/pp)